# How to initialize a vector of a class type in a constructor

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

I have a class

```
class effeid
{
public: 
 effeid(int a=0,int b=0,int c=0,int d=0):first(a),second(b),third(c),fourh(d){};

 int first;
 int second;
 int third;
 int fourh;
 };
```

and then a second class

```
class AxeEffect {
public:

//and I want to initialize the constructor in that way:

AxeEffect(int=0,string="",int=0,int=0,int=0,int=0,vector<effeid>??? );
```

How do I initialize the part with the vector to 0?

Comment: Deleted my last comment, I misunderstood. So you want the constructor of `AxeEffect` to take an std::vector as parameter? If so, what do you mean by 0?

Comment: What do you mean by 'vector to 0'? A vector of zeros (ints), or an empty vector?

Comment: Is the first class relevant to this question in any way?

Comment: I just want to avoid this every time i create an object

Comment: I just want to avoid this  AxeEffect rea(0,"",0,0,0,0,a); evry time i create an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a default argument for a `vector<T>` you simply construct one, like anything else.

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo(const vector<int> &v = vector<int>()) : _v(v) {}
private:
    vector<int> _v;
};
```

Also, I wouldn't take the `vector` by value. Take a reference to avoid an unnecessary copy.

Comment: A really great shortcut for a defaulted object in C++11 is `const vector<int> &v = {}` (yes, you did default a non-const reference to a temporary). It could have the potential to not work, but I think the class would usually be a bit oddly designed for it not to.

Comment: The best approach is to take it by value and then do `_v(std::move(v))`. This has the same number of copies in the lvalue case and one less in the rvalue case.

Comment: You have a reference to a temporary there. Why?

Comment: @sftrabbit: I'm curious. Do you mean `foo(vector<T> v)  : v(std::move(v))` is better than `foo(const vector<T> &v) : v(v)`? How about `foo(const vector<T> &v) : v(std::move(v))`?

Comment: @MM. Yes, I think so. For `foo(vector<T> v) : v(std::move(v))`: lvalue results in 1 copy, rvalue in 0 copies. For `foo(const vector<T> &v) : v(v)`: lvalue results in 1 copy, rvalue in 1 copy. For `foo(const vector<T> &v) : v(std::move(v))`: lvalue results in 1 copy, rvalue in 1 copy (can't move from a `const` ref).

Comment: @MM: `foo(const vector<T> &v) : v(std::move(v))` will give you an error, as you can't move from a const lvalue reference.

Comment: @sftrabbit: Helpful, and how about non-const `foo(vector<T> &v) : v(std::move(v))` ?

Comment: @MM. That would be a bad idea because you'd end up moving from whatever the caller passed in whether it was an lvalue or an rvalue. It would probably surprise them.